# ¿Como hacer que el cuerpo del juego snake siga la cabeza, añadiendo elementos a una lista? (en consola)

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Snake
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Snake";
            int x, y;
            x = 1;
            y = 1;
            double velocidad = 80;
            string snakeHead = "o";
            Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();

            Console.WindowHeight = 25;
            Console.WindowWidth = 80;
            Console.BufferHeight = Console.WindowHeight;
            Console.BufferWidth = Console.WindowWidth;

            string direccion = "E";

            Console.CursorVisible = false;

            try
            {
                for (;;)
                {
                    switch (direccion)
                    {
                        case "E":
                            x++;
                            break;

                        case "O":
                            x--;
                            break;

                        case "S":
                            y++;
                            break;

                        case "N":
                            y--;
                            break;
                    }

                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
                    Console.Write(snakeHead);
                    Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(velocidad));
                    velocidad = velocidad - 0.050;



                        if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                        {
                            ConsoleKey key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
                            switch (key)
                            {
                                case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                                    if ((direccion == "E") || (direccion == "O"))
                                        direccion = "S";
                                    break;
                                case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                                    if ((direccion == "N") || (direccion == "S"))
                                        direccion = "O";
                                    break;
                                case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                                    if ((direccion == "N") || (direccion == "S"))
                                        direccion = "E";
                                    break;
                                case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                                    if ((direccion == "E") || (direccion == "O"))
                                        direccion = "N";
                                    break;
                            }//fin del switch (key)
                        }//fin del if (Console.Available) 


                }
            }

            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(35, 10);
                Console.Write("Game Over");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Por favor @user7393. La pregunta debe permanecer en su estado original donde muestras el código de lo que intentaste y se puede analizar el problema. Si borras el contenido del código, la pregunta se vuelve una solicitud de código del tipo "háganme el trabajo" lo cual no es admitido en el sitio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aquí tienes otra opción usando una lista y una estructura Posicion en lugar de la estructura Point de System.Drawing.

En el caso de la lista los elementos se van añadiendo al final por lo que la cabeza de la serpiente será el último elemento, mientras que el elemento a eliminar cuando se excede la longitud (el último de la cola) será el primer elemento.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace Snake
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Snake";

            List<Posicion> snake = new List<Posicion>();
            Posicion posicionActual = new Posicion(1, 1);
            snake.Add(posicionActual);
            double velocidad = 80;
            string snakeHead = "o";
            int snakeLength = 8;

            Console.WindowHeight = 25;
            Console.WindowWidth = 80;
            Console.BufferHeight = Console.WindowHeight;
            Console.BufferWidth = Console.WindowWidth;

            string direccion = "E";

            Console.CursorVisible = false;

            try
            {
                for (;;)
                {
                    // Posición anterior de cabeza pasa a cola
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(posicionActual.X, posicionActual.Y);
                    Console.Write(snakeHead);
                    switch (direccion)
                    {
                        case "E":
                            posicionActual.X++;
                            break;

                        case "O":
                            posicionActual.X--;
                            break;

                        case "S":
                            posicionActual.Y++;
                            break;

                        case "N":
                            posicionActual.Y--;
                            break;
                    }

                    // Dibujar nueva posición cabeza
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(posicionActual.X, posicionActual.Y);
                    Console.Write(snakeHead);
                    snake.Add(posicionActual);

                    // Si la cola es más larga de la longitud máxima quitar la última
                    if (snake.Count > snakeLength)
                    {
                        Posicion primero = snake.First();
                        snake.RemoveAt(0);
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(primero.X, primero.Y);
                        Console.Write(" ");
                    }

                    Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(velocidad));
                    velocidad = velocidad - 0.050;



                    if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                    {
                        ConsoleKey key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
                        switch (key)
                        {
                            case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                                if ((direccion == "E") || (direccion == "O"))
                                    direccion = "S";
                                break;
                            case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                                if ((direccion == "N") || (direccion == "S"))
                                    direccion = "O";
                                break;
                            case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                                if ((direccion == "N") || (direccion == "S"))
                                    direccion = "E";
                                break;
                            case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                                if ((direccion == "E") || (direccion == "O"))
                                    direccion = "N";
                                break;
                        }//fin del switch (key)
                    }//fin del if (Console.Available) 


                }
            }

            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(35, 10);
                Console.Write("Game Over");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

    }

    struct Posicion
    {
        public Posicion(int x, int y)
        {
            X = x;
            Y = y;
        }

        public int X { get; set; }
        public int Y { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: ¿Es posible añadir un elemento mas a la lista al tocar otro elemento (comida)?

Comment: Tal y como está hecho no tienes más que aumentar la variable snakeLength. Según vayas aumentando el valor de la variable irá aumentando la longitud de la serpiente.

Comment: Pero se puede hacer cuando la aplicacion esta en ejecucion o lo tengo que hacer manualmente?

Comment: Puedes hacerlo en tiempo de ejecución. Ten en cuenta que no se eliminan elementos de la cola de la serpiente hasta que el número de elementos la lista supera el valor de la variable. Si aumentas el valor se mantendrán más elementos en la lista con lo que el efecto será que la serpiente ha crecido.

Comment: Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Que significa esto? (en la parte de struct)                                                                                               X = x;
Y = y;

Comment: Asigna los valores que recibe el constructor (x e y) a las propiedades (X e Y)

Answer (score 3):

Lo que deberías hacer es mantener las posiciones de todos los puntos de la culebra.

Me parece que una buena idea sería utilizar una cola de tipo Queue de forma que vas añadiendo las nuevas posiciones de la cabeza y eliminas la última en caso de superar una longitud máxima.

En lugar de limpiar toda la pantalla y volver a dibujar la serpiente, lo único que necesitarías hacer es, sobre la serpiente ya dibujada, dibujar la nueva posición de la cabeza y eliminar el carácter correspondiente al último de la cola. De esta forma lograrías el efecto del movimiento simplemente cambiando estos dos caracteres en cada iteración.

Mira este ejemplo.

Creo un objeto snake de tipo Queue en el que mantengo los diferentes puntos de la cola de la serpiente.

Establezco una variable snakeLength en la que defino la longitud máxima que debe tener la serpiente.

En cada iteración:

Escribo la posición de la anterior cabeza en blanco (ya que la cabeza la estoy escribiendo en rojo y ahora pasaría a formar parte de la cola)

Escribo la posición de la nueva cabeza en rojo y añado esta nueva posición al objeto snake.

En caso de superar la longitud máxima saco la última posición del objeto snake y escribo un espacio para eliminar el carácter de esta posición.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;

namespace Snake
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Snake";

            Queue<Point> snake = new Queue<Point>();
            Point posicionActual = new Point(1, 1);
            snake.Enqueue(posicionActual);
            double velocidad = 80;
            string snakeHead = "o";
            int snakeLength = 8;

            Console.WindowHeight = 25;
            Console.WindowWidth = 80;
            Console.BufferHeight = Console.WindowHeight;
            Console.BufferWidth = Console.WindowWidth;

            string direccion = "E";

            Console.CursorVisible = false;

            try
            {
                for (;;)
                {
                    // Posición anterior de cabeza pasa a cola
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(posicionActual.X, posicionActual.Y);
                    Console.Write(snakeHead);
                    switch (direccion)
                    {
                        case "E":
                            posicionActual.X++;
                            break;

                        case "O":
                            posicionActual.X--;
                            break;

                        case "S":
                            posicionActual.Y++;
                            break;

                        case "N":
                            posicionActual.Y--;
                            break;
                    }

                    // Dibujar nueva posición cabeza
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.SetCursorPosition(posicionActual.X, posicionActual.Y);
                    Console.Write(snakeHead);
                    snake.Enqueue(posicionActual);

                    // Si la cola es más larga de la longitud máxima quitar la última
                    if (snake.Count > snakeLength)
                    {
                        Point ultimo = snake.Dequeue();
                        Console.SetCursorPosition(ultimo.X, ultimo.Y);
                        Console.Write(" ");
                    }

                    Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(velocidad));
                    velocidad = velocidad - 0.050;



                    if (Console.KeyAvailable)
                    {
                        ConsoleKey key = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;
                        switch (key)
                        {
                            case ConsoleKey.DownArrow:
                                if ((direccion == "E") || (direccion == "O"))
                                    direccion = "S";
                                break;
                            case ConsoleKey.LeftArrow:
                                if ((direccion == "N") || (direccion == "S"))
                                    direccion = "O";
                                break;
                            case ConsoleKey.RightArrow:
                                if ((direccion == "N") || (direccion == "S"))
                                    direccion = "E";
                                break;
                            case ConsoleKey.UpArrow:
                                if ((direccion == "E") || (direccion == "O"))
                                    direccion = "N";
                                break;
                        }//fin del switch (key)
                    }//fin del if (Console.Available) 


                }
            }

            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.SetCursorPosition(35, 10);
                Console.Write("Game Over");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Para que te funcione el ejemplo deberías añadir la referencia a la librería System.Drawing para tener disponible el tipo Point.

Otra alternativa es que te crearas tu mismo un tipo para mantener cada posición:

```
struct Posicion
{
    public Posicion(int x, int y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }

    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

y cambiaras las referencias a Point por Posicion.

Comment: amigo uso el <<using System.Drawing;>> y me sigue marcando error en "Point" alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Puedes utilizar la segunda opción que te propongo de crearte una estructura Posicion y utilizar esa en su lugar. En cualquier caso comprueba que en la carpeta bin de tu proyecto existe la librería System.Drawing.dll, si no es así, haz click derecho sobre el proyecto, selecciona "Agregar referencias" y añade la referencia a System.Drawing.

Comment: @user7393 no se puede solicitar correos personales o incitar a cualquier forma de contacto privado por ningún medio. Si el usuario provee información de contacto en su perfil, puedes usar dicha información a tu disposición.

Comment: Es preferible que edites la pregunta y amplíes la información para que podamos ver el problema o, si es un problema que no tiene mucha relación con el original, abrir otra pregunta. Ten en cuenta que en las preguntas puedes incluir código e imágenes como en un correo y llega a más gente.

Comment: @AsierVillanueva Se puede cambia Queue por una "Lista"?

Comment: Sí se puede hacer, aunque por las características First In First Out de la serpiente, se van añadiendo posiciones al principio de la cola (cabeza) y se eliminan del final (cola), es más óptimo utilizar el objeto Queue. Creo otra respuesta para mostrar esta alternativa.